# Flutter: How to update app badge numbers for iOS and Android notifications?

Tags: flutter

I want to update the app badge numbers (notification badges) on the app icon in Flutter for both iOS and Android.

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to write a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **flutter_app_badger** package.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_badger